# Gradle - How to run a JAR provided by buildscript

Tags: jar, gradle, build-script

I would like to have a gradle script that executes a jar file. The problem that this jar file should be downloaded from maven central. 
I checked that the class exists in the lib.

```
apply plugin: 'application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.nativelibs4java:jnaerator:0.11"
    }
}

task x(type:JavaExec) {
    main = "com.ochafik.lang.jnaerator.JNAerator"
}
```

But when I start I get

```
╰─➤  gradle clean x
:clean UP-TO-DATE
:x
Fehler: Hauptklasse com.ochafik.lang.jnaerator.JNAerator konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden
:x FAILED
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JavaExec` forks a new process so the script classpath is gone. You need to configure it:

```
task x(type:JavaExec) {
    main = "com.ochafik.lang.jnaerator.JNAerator"
    classpath = buildscript.configurations.classpath
}
```